# React Native Redux dispatch not working but with no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I can't seem to figure out why I can't update the counter even tho I'm dispatching the correct action type and they fall within the INCREMENT and DECREMENT states. I tried passing a mapDispatchToProps and putting functions within that function and I still get the same problem, nothing updates the state for some reason.

Index:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {reducer} from './src/reducers/counter';

const store = createStore(reducer);

const Main = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Main);
```

App

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

// create a component
class App extends Component {
  increment = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'});
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT'});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onClick={this.increment} title={'Add 1'} />
        <Text>Counter {this.props.count} </Text>
        <Button onClick={this.decrement} title={'Subtract 1'} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Counter

```
const initState = {
  count: 1,
};

export const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return {
        count: state.count + 1,
      };
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return {
        count: state.count - 1,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is React Native app, right?  Your error is that you used `onClick` for the `Button` instead of `onPress`.  [It works fine now](https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/surprised-coffee) after switching that prop name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the App component into the redux store with `connect` function.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// create a component
class App extends Component {
  increment = () => {
    this.props.increment();
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.props.decrement();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={this.increment} title={'Add 1'} />
        <Text>Counter {this.props.count} </Text>
        <Button onPress={this.decrement} title={'Subtract 1'} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ count: state.count })
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
    decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: I had connected both but I wrote it under my styles so I didn't copy/paste it over. Still doesn't do anything to count, unfortunately.

Comment: @azimov308 Did you check if the button click event called correctly?

Comment: in the increment function I changed this.props.increment() to this.props.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'}); and it still doesn't work. Dispatch receives the correct action but doesn't handle it correctly.

Comment: @azimov308 I think the button click action is not working on your code, as I mentioned before.

Comment: The problem was I used onClick instead of onPress, thanks!

Comment: @azimov308 Right, could you upvote my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

These point need to be taken care of in order for this to work:

1. Change the prop onClick to onPress
2. Create a constructor in the App Component, to bind "this" to the increment, decrement action creator functions. Like this:

> 

```
constructor() {
    super(props)
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
}
```

3. Lastly, connect to Redux store, and dispatch the actions like ,in AlphaDevs's Answer